# A plague of innocuous tag edits

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Over the last 10-20 minutes there has been an absolute plague of tag edits, in particular from one user - [GreenHorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/333521/greenhorn?tab=activity#apage_1-afilter_revisions).

Now I'm all in favour of people being active, but when someone is clearly trawling the `c++` tag and adding tags of `syntax` or `pointers` to screeds of questions then it is getting beyond a joke. Is there a daily limit on how many tag edits someone can propose? Or is it rate limit, so they can only do *x* per hour?

I'm fully aware of the fact that he will lose rep and be temporarily banned from suggesting edits if too many are rejected, but it takes time to go through these and check them, and I'm also concerned that some approvers may just hit that big old Approve button too readily, which feeds the behaviour.

If the proposal rate for tags is limited then it will cut down on this behaviour.

Comment: Typical case of user looking for quick and easy reputation.. there is limit of amount of suggested edits per day think it's 20 or 30.

Comment: Don't worry, as far as I know the mods/devs have a mass-undo-tool at their service (they keep him locked in the basement, but I didn't tell you that!). :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not really sure that there's anything *wrong* with adding more descriptive tags to questions as has been done. In particular, if a C++ question is specifically about pointers, it's very useful for it to have both a [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and a [pointers](/questions/tagged/pointers) tag. These aren't meta tags; they actually (or at least, potentially) describe the content of the question. So I don't really think that a moderator-induced "mass-undo" is the appropriate course of action here.

That being said, mass tag edits like this are not good for anyone. Bumping old questions just to edit tags is never a good idea, and the user probably doesn't deserve the reputation points he's getting each time that his edits are being approved.

If you think this is abusive, just start **rejecting** his proposed edits. After a certain number of edits get rejected, he'll be banned from suggesting any more for 7 days. You're right that not enough people use that reject button. It's there for a reason.

Comment: That was the problem i was having with these particular edits - just because the OP *mentioned* the word 'pointer' doesn't mean it needed to be added as a tag, and `string-manipulation` didn't need to be added because there was a string in the OP's code. For this user i accepted two tag edits and rejected about 2 dozen, he was really on a crusade for easy rep.

Comment: I disagree in this specific case. Those retags are spurious, and their only goal is to whore points. They add zero value to the question.

Comment: @slugster: Yeah, I didn't really check the edits proposed by that specific user. The first paragraph was more general, based on the explanation in your question. I suspect you're right about this *specific* case, the user is just looking for easy rep. In that case, that's what the reject button is for. I've also discovered that once there's a reject vote, it makes others more likely to click it too (or at least gives them pause before blindly clicking accept).

Comment: yeah. I flagged a question for mod attention - this deserves bigger guns than a few users rejecting his edits IMO

Comment: @Pekka: I'm still not convinced that an outright **ban** is in order. None of the tags he's proposed look downright *wrong* to me. Several of the edits he's made are ones I might make myself. But I agree that a moderator could contact the user and ask him to stop abusing the system in this way. It's most likely a problem of ignorance. We only need bigger guns if that fails. The best thing to suggest to him is to fix *other* things in the question while he's at it, rather than simply adding tags.